# S-tec 50 with gns 430

Tags: navigation

S Tec 50 with an gas 430 navigation question 
flying  a 172p with a gns430 and an s-tec 50 , my question is to fly a gps track the 50 has to be in just nav mode ? Some Manuel’s say apr should be on also ? ... hdg mode just follows bug (plane has an hsi)

Comment: Might be worthwhile asking your question in a way that would pass muster with a 5th grade English teacher: complete sentence with a subject & verb, punctuation in the appropriate places, etc.  Also, read over the question to see if it makes basic sense as stated. This community can probably provide the answer to the question I ***think*** you are asking, but getting that answer is a lot more likely if you would take the time to at least make your question legible on first glance.

Comment: Read the supplement in the POH that is required for these types of complex navigation systems with unique attributes.  A short, serious answer is that there is no rule, in the same way that televisions use different menus and navigation paradigms for you to select the video source.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is, it depends on if the plane also has a GPSS (GPS Steering) data converter installed between the GNS-430 and the S-TEC. See my question and answer here regarding how GPSS works in this system - that is, feeding GPS nav data to an S-TEC 50 autopilot. I had the same question about the same setup in my Grumman Tiger.

I found the S-TEC 50 to be an excellent autopilot!

[What are the differences between a GPS coupled autopilot and a GPSS autopilot?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/21577/what-are-the-differences-between-a-gps-coupled-autopilot-and-a-gpss-autopilot)